# Client Server hypothetical questions

Tags: architecture, tcp, udp, client-server, handshake

Video server – recording / playback / preview/ export/ copy  live streaming.

Controller - video server remote control.

In network can be many servers and controllers.

Each controller can connect to multiple video servers.

Video servers do not connected to each other unless there is operation running on both of 
them initiated by controller (like copy data).

Each video servers can be physically plug / unplug to network at any time.

Video servers and controllers connected by Ethernet.

1. Server IP is unknown to controller. Currently each video server sending periodic (every 100 millisecond) multicast message contain personal information (IP, free available port…) and notify everyone in group that he is alive. Is that good solution?
2. When user like to make data copy from one server to another number of copy operation is limited. If servers not connected  how controller begin copy operation , I mean does he first capture resource on both servers and then tell then to start communicate between them or pass data of one server to another so he will connection process ?
   Thanks.

Comment: What's the controller's job? What do you mean with "Live periodic event ????" - The latter one is bad style, because you simply throw in some words which you do not connect well into the context of the question.

Comment: server is storage for live video stream.

Comment: controller is how user control video stream (copy ,export , play..)

Comment: Live periodic event - server send multicast event on start mode with free port available

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting it. You have to think from the perspective of the person you are asking, not your perspective. When explaining, imagine you were explaining the whole thing to a 3 years old child. You will then give enough context automatically.

Comment: Sorry. I write again.